# Find second smallest value of a vector

Tags: vector, scheme, racket, minimum

I have construced a procedure which should take an argument, a vector with numbers as entries, and then return the lowest value.

```
(define min-number
  (lambda (vec)
    (define looping
      (lambda (i v-min)
        (if (= i (vector-length vec))
            v-min
            (looping (+ i 1) (min v-min (vector-ref vec i))))))
    (looping 1 (vector-ref vec 0))

    )
  )
```

Now I want to construct a procedure which returns the second smallest value of a vector. This is something which should be done without converting the vector to a list. Any ideas of how I could do so? I can't get my head out of the "list-thinking". My head says to me "use car", "use cdr" and so on which doesn't work in this particular case. So any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Hmm, I think I covered everything, if something is unclear, let me know.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed to use built-in functions, here's an easy way: find the minimum value, and then look for the next minimum value which is *not* that minimum. This is what I mean:

```
(define min-number
  (lambda (vec)
    (let ((min-val (vector-argmin identity vec)))
      (vector-argmin
       (lambda (x) (if (equal? x min-val) +inf.0 x))
       vec))))
```

For example:

```
(min-number '#(5 4 1 2 3))
=> 2
```

Comment: Thanks, think this will do it :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, similar to Óscar's answer in that both are O(n). This one works for any sequences, including lists and vectors!

```
(define (second-lowest seq)
  (define-values (_ x)
    (for/fold ((a #f) (b #f))
              ((x seq))
      (cond ((< x (or a (add1 x))) (values x a))
            ((< x (or b (add1 x))) (values a x))
            (else (values a b)))))
  x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finding the kth smallest element of a vector is nicely solved by the quickselect algorithm.

```
(define (quickselect A k)
  (define pivot (list-ref A (random (length A))))
  (define A1 (filter (curry > pivot) A))
  (define A2 (filter (curry < pivot) A))
  (cond
    [(<= k (length A1)) (quickselect A1 k)]
    [(> k (- (length A) (length A2))) (quickselect A2 (- k (- (length A) (length A2))))]
    [else pivot]))

(quickselect '(9 8 7 6 5 0 1 2 3 4) 2)  ; => 1
```

Code from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quickselect_algorithm#Racket

Comment: Why so many O(n) operations? ;'( (That's Rosetta Code for you, I guess.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young  You are right - this version is not an example of efficient code. I have written a `vector-select` from scratch. See the new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two versions of `vector-select` which finds the kth smallest element in a vector `v`. This means that `(vector-select v 1)` finds the second smallest element in a vector. The difference between `vector-select` and `vector-select!` is that the latter might change the order of the elements in the vector. Both procedures have an expected time of `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the vector.

```
#lang racket
; vector-ref and vector-set! is used so often, so introduce shorter notation
(define-syntax-rule (vref  v i)   (vector-ref  v i))
(define-syntax-rule (vset! v i e) (vector-set! v i e))

; vector-select : vector index -> number
;   find the kth largest element of v
;   (where 0 <= k < n )
(define (vector-select v k) 
  (define n (vector-length v))
  (unless (<= 0 k (- n 1))
    (error 'vector-select "expected a number between 0 and the length of the vector"))
  (subvector-select! (vector-copy v) k 0 n))

; vector-select! : vector index -> number
;   find the kth largest element of v
;   (where 0 <= k < n )
;   side effect: the order of the elements may change
(define (vector-select! v k) 
  (define n (vector-length v))
  (unless (<= 0 k (- n 1))
    (error 'vector-select! "expected a number between 0 and the length of the vector"))
  (subvector-select! v k 0 n))

; subvector-select : vector index index index -> number
;   find the kth largest element of the elements v[s],v[s+1],...,v[t-1].
;   assumption: s<t  (i.e. the subvector is non-empty)
(define (subvector-select! v k s t)
  (define n (- t s)) ; length of subvector
  (cond
    [(= n 1) (unless (= k 0) (error "Error 1"))
             (vref v s)]
    [else    (define r (randomized-partion! v s t)) ; v[r] is a pivot
             (define l (- r s))                     ; number of elements left of pivot (in subvector)
             (cond
               [(= k l) (vref v r)]                             ; found it!
               [(< k l) (subvector-select! v    k     s r)]     ; the element is left  of the pivot
               [else    (subvector-select! v (- k l)  r t)])])) ; the element is right of the pivot

; randomized-partion! : vector index index -> index
;   Pick a random index between s and t, then partion the elements
;   in the subvector v[s],v[s+1],...,v[t-1] using v[r] as pivot.
;   I.e. move elements smaller than the pivot to appear before the pivot
;   and  move elements larger  than the pivot to appear after  the pivot.
;   Finally return the index of the pivot.
(define (randomized-partion! v s t)
  ;; Helper
  ; swap! : index index -> void
  ;   swap elements with index i and j
  (define (swap! i j) 
    (define vi (vref v i))          
    (vset! v i (vref v j))          
    (vset! v j vi))
  ;; Main
  (define r (+ s (random (- t s)))) ; pick random pivot index in subvector
  (define p (vref v r))             ; the pivot value
  (swap! (- t 1) r)                 ; place the pivot as the last value in the subvector
  (define i s)                      ; invariant: all elements before v[i] are <= pivot
  (for ([j (in-range s (- t 1))])   ;   loop through all elements (except the pivot)
    (when (<= (vref v j) p)         ;     if the element is non-greater than the pivot
      (swap! i j)                   ;       move it to the front of the subvector
      (set! i (+ i 1))))            ;       and update i to the next available slot
  (swap! i (- t 1))
  i)                                ;   finally put the pivot in place
```